# How to do re-export with overrides?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

```
export * form 'some-library'
export * from './myOverrides'
// error: [ts] Module 'some-module' has already
// exported a member named 'someFunc'.
// Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.

import * as SomeLib from 'some-library'
import * as MyOverrides from './myOverrides'

export { ...SomeLib, ...MyOverrides } // syntax error

const Overridden = { ...someLib, ...MyOverrides } // works
export { ...Overridden } // syntax error
```

I would like to avoid picking out all named exports just to re-export them;

```
import { a, b, c, d, e, ..... } from 'some-library'
export { a, b, c, d, e, .... }
export * from './myOverrides'
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no clean way to do this, and no proposals for any way to do this in the future. (It does seem useful though!)

Comment: Hi @JKillian !, see the answer below. I dig up some issues and found it. :)

Comment: Hey @unional! :)  Yes, it's good that solutions works for what you need! However, you still have to pick out your overrides individually. I couldn't find a way to do it where you could get the overrides to be exported without ever specifically naming them.

Comment: Yes indeed. But at least I can do that only for the overrides, not the original library. So it should be only a few (finger crossed). :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [Guy Sensei](https://github.com/guybedford):

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1031#issuecomment-171262430

I need to:

```
import { theFunction } from './myOverrides'

export * from 'some-library'
export { theFunction }
```

This works because local exports take priority.

Answer (score 9):

I found this to work quite nicely:

```js
import * as packageA from "packageA";
import * as packageB from "packageB";

export default { ...packageA, ...packageB };
```

Comment: This won't work if those packages contain interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export the whole module:

```
export * as MyOverrides from './myOverrides'
```

and then you can use it in another file as:

```
import { MyOverrides } from './some-path'

MyOverrides.someFunc
```